# Can we create Crow Foot notation of zero or one cardinality in a pgadmin ERD?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, erd

I have this:

[image]

I wanna change the users table to this:

[image]

I added nullable constraint on `usersId` in the `orders` table but that didn't change anything on the ERD. Is this a problem with pgadmin or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: if `orders (usersId)` is nullable, then that's enough for the cardinality to be optional (aka 0:1). There must be an issue with the drawing tool.

Answer (score 2):

The ERD diagramming tool of pgadmin seems designed to represent only one-to-many and many-to-many relations.

It is [not capable (yet?)](https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/5128) of representing simple one-to-one relations, and seems not capable either according to the screenshots in the  documentation to indicate optional or mandatory participation in a relation (e.g. double bar or circle bar).

The best way forward would be to [log an issue](https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues) in pgadmin's official issue tracker.